# Jhipster adding more fields to user registration

Tags: json, spring, jhipster

I have a little problem with Jhipster framework.

I want to make a few more fields to a new user registration by anonymous person.
Want to make, that database would not only register User login, password and email, but also firstName, and LastName.

I added those forms in registration.html file.

After I submitted the "post" action there that kind of JSON file is generated:

{"password":"aaaaaa","login":"20124668","firstname":"Jack","lastname":"Jackson","email":"jack.jackson@gmail.com","langKey":"en"}

I understand, that in back-end the responsible method for registering new user is this:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/register",
 method = RequestMethod.POST,
 produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
 @Timed
 public ResponseEntity<?> registerAccount(@Valid @RequestBody UserDTO userDTO, HttpServletRequest request) {
 return userRepository.findOneByLogin(userDTO.getLogin())
```

The question is, why database did not save the firstName and the lastName, but did save others???

Comment: Which version of jhipster? Which database? Have you modified UserDTO and User classes ? and BTW JHipster is not framework, it's an application generator.

Comment: Hello, I am using Jhipster 1.6.0 version. The database is Postgres 1.43.3 version. I have not modified the userDTO nor the User class, because it simply has those fields.

Comment: Sorry I can't help you, 1.6.0 is too old, current one is 2.27.2 and 3.0 is expected within few weeks

Comment: I have installed it like two in a half month ago. Strange

Comment: JHipster version can be found in your .yo-rc.json file in your generated project, I guess you gave yeoman version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"firstname" field should be named "firstName" and "lastname" should be "lastName" in your JSON POST request. In current version these fields are already included in registration form so you should consider upgrading.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem. Thank you.